# Business Objects Reporting Standards

Tags: business-objects

We are trying to set our BI team's reporting standards for Business Objects Universe Designer and Web Intelligence tools. We set some standars like below.

What are your ideas about these standards? Could you please share your standards documents?

- Name the universe based on the application.
- Give proper name universe objects (classes, dimensions, measures etc) according to
  business terminology and being explicit in the definition. For
  instance, an object called 'Sales' could be interpreted many
  different ways. Is it Sales Revenue, Count of Sales Orders, Count of
  Sales Order Lines, Average Sales Amount.
- Company logo is put on the upperleft side of the report.
- User prompts and last refresh time is put on the upper-right side of the report.
- The title and report name describes the scope of the data (for example, university wide, unit specific, school/college level) and any conditions in the report (for example, term, fiscal year, department ID).
- The columns of data are arranged in logical order.
- When prompts are used, they model how the data should be entered. For example, “Enter the term (e.g. 1760)”

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a bit off topic for stackoverflow, and some of it is not clear or is commonsense anyway (eg. "columns of data arranged in logical order"), but I would suggest:

1. that every universe be associated with a three character code (eg. SAL, REV etc).
2. that every report be uniquely identifiable by a number, prefixed by the Universe code.
3. that non-trivial objects have as part of their definition a SQL-format comment giving their name and folder.

Answer (score 0):

There two aspects :

- Considering the technical aspect of the universe
- Considering the end-user aspect of the universe

Technical aspects :

- Layout of your tables should reflect your navigation
- Version information/changes in either comment / hidden objects
- try to use aliases as much as possible to show in what function your table is used.
- try to refactor used constants in separate objects and use the @select to use them.
- try to have a hierarchic naming convention so that the name will imply the navigation.
- find a fitting naming convention for your connections.

User aspects :

- DON'T DO THIS folder = table name , object = column name, it comes from dragging and dropping your tables.
- object name is not literature, you are limited. It should be clear what the object is. Add comments always comments.
- Limit number of folders, limit folder depth, limit number of objects in a folder.
- Order the objects based on their use inside folder(most used on top).